# HTML Navigation bar disappearing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have created a website for my school work and I am trying to implement a navigation bar for all the pages of the site. I got it working on all my other pages but there is one page in particular where it the entire navigation bar disappears when the page is loaded. The header section should display the navigation bar while the body loads the prime number table.[The page should have a navbar like this.](http://w3.cnm.edu/~tteichelmann/cis1210/chapter1/)
However the prime number table page will not load the home and back icons.

I cant get the stackoverflow formatter to accept my html code so I have to put a link to it, sorry!.

[This is the source code](http://w3.cnm.edu/~tteichelmann/cis1210/chapter3/source%20code.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Headers should not be in the `<head>` element; instead, they should be at the top of the `<body>` element.  So move this code:

```
<div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <a class="logo" href="http://w3.cnm.edu/~tteichelmann"></a>
                    <a class="back" href="http://w3.cnm.edu/~tteichelmann/cis1210" onclick="history.back();" value="Back"></a>

                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Into the body.  Also, HTML 5 introduced the `<header>` element ([more here](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/)), which is a more syntactical way of defining a header... Consider that an alternative, not a requirement.

Comment: I appreciate the help with cleaning up my code. However moving the section you specified into the body element didn't fix my problem. I need the navigation bar that has the home and back icons to not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Move your div with the class of header outside of the head section of the document. It should be within the body tags.

Comment: I moved the div tags into the body section but it did not fix my problem. The home and back buttons that I require still do not show up on the page.

Comment: can you place your code o jsFiddle or somewhere where we can see all of it. Like your css as well as the html. In the link you provided there is only the raw source without the ability to access the styles